# why is ng-model not checking default radio button?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Below is the fiddle i am working:

http://jsfiddle.net/3c0dxf4d/

The `ng-model` has an object and the `ng-value` maps to object, why is my default value `{"id":1,"name":"Bill"}`
 not getting selected by default.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/roz98eda/

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.customers = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Bill"
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Bob"
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Biff"
  }];
  $scope.customer = {};
  $scope.currentCustomer = {
    "id": 1
  };

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="theCustomer in customers">
        <td>
          <input type="radio" ng-model="$parent.currentCustomer.id" ng-value="theCustomer.id">{{theCustomer.name}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <div>{{currentCustomer}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you've put the initial value to 
$scope.currentCustomer = {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Bill"
    };

Just remove or change it.
Please check following code please.

app.controller("ctrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.customers = [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Bill"
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Bob"
    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Biff"
    }];
    $scope.customer = {};

```
*$scope.currentCustomer = {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Bill"
};*
```

})

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="$parent.currentCustomer" name="foo" ng-value="theCustomer" id="{{theCustomer.id}}">
```

To

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="$parent.currentCustomer.id" name="foo" ng-value="theCustomer.id" id="{{theCustomer.id}}">{{theCustomer.name}}</td>
```

From `ng-value` docs

> It is mainly used on input[radio] and option elements, so that when
>   the element is selected, the ngModel of that element (or its select
>   parent element) is set to the bound value.